# best practice for handling exceptions in Background threads in Android apps

Tags: java, android, multithreading, exception, background

I've got multiple try/catch blocks in my background thread which initialize and load data/DB. 
At first I just placed `throw new RuntimeException( e );` in the catches , but I think I should be handling them instead of just throwing them hoping for someone to handle that.. in which case ,by the way, the app will just crash.

What is the best practice handling these situations(in background threads), particularly in Android apps ?

Thanks.

EDIT :

```
private static class DatabaseLoaderHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static String DB_PATH = "" ;

    private DatabaseLoaderHelper( WeakReference<Context> contextWrapper )
    {
        super( contextWrapper.get(), DB_NAME , null, DB_VERSION );
        DB_PATH = contextWrapper.get().getDatabasePath( DB_NAME ).getAbsolutePath();

        boolean dataBaseExist = checkDatabaseExist( contextWrapper );
        if ( !dataBaseExist )
        {
            try
            {
                copyDatabase( contextWrapper.get() );
            }
            catch ( IOException e )
            {
                throw new RuntimeException( e );

            }
        }
    }

    private void copyDatabase( Context context ) throws IOException
    {
        InputStream myInput = null;
        String outFileName = null;
        OutputStream myOutput = null;

        try
        {
            myInput = context.getAssets().open( DB_NAME );

            outFileName = DB_PATH;

            myOutput = new FileOutputStream( outFileName );

            byte[] buffer = new byte[ 1024 ];
            int length;

            while ( ( length = myInput.read( buffer ) ) > 0 )
            {
                myOutput.write( buffer, 0, length );
            }
        }      
        catch( IOException e )
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDatabaseExist( WeakReference<Context> contextWrapper )
    {

        File dbFile = new File( DB_PATH + DB_NAME );
        if ( !dbFile.getParentFile().exists() )
        {
            dbFile.getParentFile().mkdir();
            return false;
        }
        return dbFile.exists();
    }
```

Comment: It depends on the type of exception and what could cause it to happen. There's really no universal answer. Perhaps if you change the question and provide more specific information, we can suggest an approach that is suitable for that situation. Things like, is this just within your own app, or do you expect third parties to be calling your app/using your data through some IPC mechanism (intents, bound services, ContentProvider, etc)? Do you have suitable fallbacks when these exceptions happen? Do these exceptions actually happen? etc.

Comment: I've added in the post a brief of the program that has a few exceptions I need to handle somehow. It's subclass of SQLOpenHelper ,which is initialized and called in doInBackground() .
Thanks.
Btw, I also don't know what to do in the Finally where I close the resource files. For example , if myOutput.close() will throw an exception - myInput.close() won't be called... How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an AsyncTask it is a common practice to catch the Exception in doBackground() and assign it to a class member Exception variable and handle it in onPostExecute().